# How to convert spring boot long to date

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
private long date;
```

How to customize time formatting ex yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss , yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: can you add more code or please try to explain it in better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use @JsonSerialize to convert your long millisecond to desired date format.

Here is the sample.

**Pojo Class**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.util.Pair;

/**
 * Created by yprajapati on 19/09/2019.
 */

public @Data
class Test {

    private long date;

    @JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializerCustom.class)
    private Pair formattedDate;

    public Pair getFormattedDate() {
        return Pair.of(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"); // Here you can add your desired date format
    }
}
```

**Date Serializer**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import org.springframework.data.util.Pair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

/**
 * Created by yprajapati on 19/09/2019.
 */

public class DateSerializerCustom extends JsonSerializer<Pair<Long, String>> {

    public void serialize(Pair<Long, String> pair, JsonGenerator jsonGen, SerializerProvider serProv) throws IOException {
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pair.getSecond());
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(pair.getFirst());
        jsonGen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

**Main App**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * Created by yprajapati on 19/09/2019.
 */

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setDate(1568866827596L);

        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(test));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
{"date":1568866827596,"formattedDate":"2019-09-19 09:50"}
```

Note: Here I have added extra field. Mark it as `@Transient` as it will not be a part of persistent.

Comment: Thanks, if you need to define ex in different pojo classes; 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' , 'yyyy-MM-dd' .. ?

Comment: In that case, I would suggest you use separate field of type Pair(https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/util/Pair.html) which will send longDate and dateFormat to the serializer and do the processing.

example:  Pair.of(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

Comment: Please update your question and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Pair  Where should I put?

Comment: Please update your question so I can update my answer against it. I have developed generic date serializer which accept longDate and outputDateFormat.